# How to run background process one after another

Tags: perl, cgi

I am using Perl CGI. I am running an SCP command via Perl CGI in the background. Like

```
system("scp -r machinename:/PathOfFile/ /Path/WhereToCopyIt/  &")
```

This copy process takes some time, let's say 15 min. 
Now I want when this copy process is complete then send me an email.
But my problem is this command is running in the background. So how can i send a mail?
I know how to send mail but i don't know how to send mail when process is running in the background.

Answer (score 5):

Why not [`fork`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/fork.html)?

```
my $pid = fork;

if ( $pid == 0 ) {   # Child

    exec( ... );  # Without the '&'
    exit( $? >> 8 );
}

else {               # Parent

    waitpid $pid, 0;
}
```

---

See [`perldoc perlfork`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfork.html) and [`perldoc perlipc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html)for more <sub>(perhaps too much?)</sub> information.

Answer (score 1):

Start a background job which performs the actions in sequence.  Basically

```
system(qq'sh -c "scp -r machinename:/PathOfFile/ /Path/WhereToCopyIt/; 
          echo Done | /sendmail you@example.net" &')
```

You probably want to encapsulate the background script into a separate file, or at least add some error checking.